# Is there a way to make a pass over two llvm-ir?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to compare two llvm-ir programs function by function. I thought it will be help full if I do it as an LLVM pass where I can have access to CFG of the program. It seems all the passes(Module, Function, ..) were working on single program, How can I do a pass over two programs simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I would just run [llvm-link](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-link.html) (a command-line tool bundled with LLVM) to merge the IR files together first, then use a regular module pass.

I think the function renaming rule in llvm-link is something like renaming `f` to `f.llvm.X` where `X` is the module ID, so your pass could identify pairs by them having the same name prefix before the module ID.